# WebException: The operation has timed out TCP or HTTP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, tcp

On tcp timeout to open a connection to a server if there is a timeout. What exception is thrown in .net

Does the exception **WebException: The operation has timed out** occur on TCP timeout as well, if so is there any way to figure out if it was an HTTP or TCP timeout? Or is there a different exception?

Code to make a request

```
         try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.Timeout = 5000;
                var response = request.GetResponse();
                response.Close();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                SendException(ex, url);
            }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Also, you should have `using (var response = request.GetResponse());` or the response won't get cleaned up in the case of an exception.

Comment: This timeout is very specifically part of the HTTP connection, which you can control, and not a TCP timeout, which you generally cannot control. TCP timeouts can be controlled by the server, but not the client.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Trying to figure out if when the timeout's happen will we see the requests in the http log of the remote server. If they were TCP level timeout's we wont.